# new line in java

Tags: java, netbeans

Java newbie here, I'm having trouble setting a new line in this code:

```
String FnameTextboxText   = FnameTextbox.getText();
          String LastnameTextboxText   = LastnameTextbox.getText();
            String CourseTextboxText   = CourseTextbox.getText();
                Summary.setText("Firstname:" + " " + FnameTextboxText + "\nLastname:" + " " + LastnameTextboxText + "\nCourse:" + " " + CourseTextboxText);
```

Also tried something like: `"\n" + "Lastname"` But its no good.
Do you have any idea on how to make new lines. So that it'll look like this;

```
    Firstname: x 
   Lastname: y 
    Course: Z
```

Using netbeans 6.8. On windows.

Comment: What is the type of `Summary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use TextArea.

Answer (score 0):

First, use TextArea
Second, test using \r or \n or \r\n
Sometimes, people use \n to make new line and sometimes, like me, use \r\n to make new line

Comment: or simply `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, so that you are really cross platform...